# Azure AD not providing objectidentifier claim for Chrome users

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, active-directory, claims

We have an ASP.Net MVC 5 application which is authenticating against an Azure AD.

We want to get the objectidentifier from the ClaimsPrincipal when the user browses to a controller action and so we use the following code:

```
var objectIdentifier = Guid.Parse(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity)
   .FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier")
   .Value);
```

This works absolutely as expected in IE 11 - identity has 9 claims on it, including the objectidentifier.

When we run exactly the same code but log in using Chrome, the identity only has 7 claims on it and it does not include objectidentifier.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to answer my own question, but it turns out the the two browsers we logging in using 2 different user identities, one of which was a user in the AAD and the other was a LiveId added to the AAD. The latter has fewer properties associated with it, including no objectidentifier.

Comment: what about "oid" shortname?